# Converting a list of items in qt listwidget to radio buttons

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlistwidget, qradiobutton

I have created an application where files from a directory are being displayed in the qlistwidget.

Now the problem is that I want this list to be shown as a list of radio buttons so that the user can select a radio button and the address of the selected file can be saved. Also an error need to be shown if the user doesn't select a radio button and clicks next.

I'm using Visual Studio for coding the gui instead of qt creator.

My code so far is:

**.hpp file**

```
#pragma once
#include <QWidget>

#include "ui_secondform.h"

#include "thirdform.hpp"
#include <QRegExp>
#include <QDir>
#include <QDebug>

class SecondForm : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    SecondForm(QWidget * parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    ~SecondForm();
    QString processText();
signals:
    void firstform();
public slots:
    void on_pushButton_next2_clicked();
    void on_pushButton_back2_clicked();
    void on_lineEdit_textChanged(const QString &arg1);
    //void onNewTextEntered(const QString &text);
    //void on_lineEdit_textChanged(const QString &arg1);
private:
    Ui::SecondForm ui;
    ThirdForm *third;
    QStringList fileList;
};
```

**.cpp file:**

```
#include "secondform.hpp"
#include "firstform.h"

SecondForm::SecondForm(QWidget * parent) : QWidget(parent) {
    ui.setupUi(this);
    third = new ThirdForm();
    // connected to the slot start the main window on the button in the second window
    connect(third, &ThirdForm::secondform, this, &SecondForm::show);
    //QString dir = processText();
    QDir testPath("D://");
    testPath.setFilter(QDir::Dirs | QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
    fileList = testPath.entryList();
    ui.listWidget->addItems(fileList);
}

SecondForm::~SecondForm() {

}
void SecondForm::on_pushButton_back2_clicked() {
    this->hide();
    emit firstform();
}
void SecondForm::on_pushButton_next2_clicked() {
    this->close();
    third->show();
}
void SecondForm::on_lineEdit_textChanged(const QString &arg1) {
    QRegExp regExp(arg1, Qt::CaseInsensitive, QRegExp::Wildcard);
    ui.listWidget->clear();
    ui.listWidget->addItems(fileList.filter(regExp));
}
QString SecondForm::processText()
{
    FirstForm first;
    const QString dir = first.lineEdit()->text();
    return dir;
    // do something with the text
}
```

**Output:**

[image: image for output]

Comment: You could explain yourself better, you could show a picture of what you want to get.

Comment: The dont need to be radio buttons for that. Just use the selected index.

Comment: @eyllanesc i just want the same output but the stuff in listwidget needs to be in radio boxes

Comment: @Mike could you tell how I could do that or link me to a website that could explain that, like I said I am very new to qt.

Comment: So your using a list widget. That has member fuctions that return active properities of the object. It emits signals... you can use the signals and make slots to handle them (i. e. Save the files) or you can use the object directly. QListWidget::itemClicked signal is probably what you want. Tie it to a slot that takes a QListWidgetItem*  param and there you go.

Comment: Or whenever you hit the end button to perform the action use functions QListWidget:: currentIndex, currentItem, currentRow, etc. you have control of the selection behavior and appearance.

Comment: @Mike I want to make sure that the user only selects one item, how do i do that

Comment: SetSelectionBehavior function takes a single selection flag i believe. And if you want some icon to denote selection next to the text you can do that too!

Comment: @Mike thanks so much! I have a different question, not related to this topic. In QFileDialog::getOpenFileName how do I add a default directory of my own choice dynamically? What happens is that the user selects the directory through a different push button and after that I want him to select a file in that directory through another pushButton. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: *if i understand correctly* if you can get the entryInfoList () (a QDir call) or obtain the files/dirs in the location yoy can sort by time or alphabetically and selcet take the fileName() and set it to a class member m_selectedFile upon initialization of the listWidget. Then if the user clicks a button that file will already be queued. How you want to visually represent that it is selected would be to setSelected () on the listWidget.